# ASP.NET radio button change

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to figure out why this code doesn't fire the radio button change event.

here's the ASP page code for 2 radio buttons

```
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoButton1" GroupName="Group1" Text="Yes" Value="Yes"  runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Group1_CheckedChanged" />
  <asp:RadioButton ID="rdoButton2" GroupName="Group1" Text="No" Value="No" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Group1_CheckedChanged" />
```

And here's the code behind:

```
protected void Group1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rdoButton1.Checked) {
        panel1.Visible = true;
    }

    if (rdoButton2.Checked) {
        panel1.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You'll need to specify the attribute and value [`AutoPostBack="true"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback.aspx) in order to tell ASP.NET that changing of *that* element should trigger a postback. It should be applied to each individual RadioButton which you wish to cause a postback.

Answer (score 7):

You should add the `AutoPostBack=True` attribute to both controls.

Comment: But enclosing the value in quotes would be recommended.

Comment: AutoPostBack="true"

Answer (score 4):

you have to specify the `AutoPostBack=True`  for both controls

Answer (score 3):

I would use `RadioButtonList` instead. And set `AutoPostBack=true` for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the AutoPostBack = True and in the code behind the handles in your function.

Example:

```
Protected Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)           Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify `AutoPostBack=True` in both the Radio Button Control to solve the issue

like this:

> <asp:RadioButton `AutoPostBack=True` ID="rdoButton1" GroupName="Group1" Text="Yes"
> Value="Yes"  runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Group1_CheckedChanged"
> />
> <asp:RadioButton  `AutoPostBack=True` ID="rdoButton2" GroupName="Group1" Text="No"
> Value="No" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Group1_CheckedChanged" />