# How to register an event for a RadioButton group?

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like some help/explanation/clarification on the following issue:

I have a `TreeView` item nested in an `Expander`, that host `RadioButton` controls based on different branching options, the same property needs to be changed. The radio buttons are all assigned to the same group.

```
   <Expander x:Name="expanderInterestStructure" Header="Interest Structure" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,138,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="132" BorderThickness="0">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="inputInterestStructureSelection" Margin="0,0,-131,-177" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <TreeViewItem Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Header="360">
                <RadioButton x:Name="_360fixed" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="360fixed" Content="Fixed Interest" IsChecked="True"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Compund Interest">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_360compDay" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="360compDay" Content="Daily"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_360compMonth" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="360compMonth" Content="Monthly"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_360compQuater" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="360compQuater" Content="Quaterly"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_360compYear" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="360compYear" Content="Yearly"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  Header="365/366">
                <RadioButton  x:Name="_365fixed" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="365fixed" Content="Fixed Interest"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Compund Interest">
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_365compDay" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="365compDay" Content="Daily"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_365compMonth" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="365compMonth" Content="Monthly"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_365compQuater" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="365compQuater" Content="Quaterly"/>
                    <RadioButton x:Name="_365compYear" GroupName="interestStructure" Tag="365compYear" Content="Yearly"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>

    </Grid>
</Expander>
```

The question is, how can i register an event that monitors this **group** and if the selection among group members changes, it sets a string property to the selected items tag or name?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you need to handle this on each radio button, not at the group level.  You'll need to assign AutoPostBack = "True" and associate your method with OnCheckedChanged.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8095256/asp-net-radio-button-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no group**s**, all `RadioButton`s are in same group (`GroupName="interestStructure"`).

Anyhow, you can subscribe each `RadioButton` to same event handler:

```
<RadioButton ... Checked="radioButton_Checked"/>
```

Inside which you can put all the logic:

```
void radioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var radioButton = (RadioButton)sender; // checked RadioButton

    // logic
    if(radioButton == _360CompDay)
        button.Tag = "whatever";
    else if ...
}
```